# Is it correct to say "drive out" when someone is actually driving out of something?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I went to a concert with a group of friends, and after the concert one of us was giving a lift to the others. Her car was parked tightly in between other cars, so it would be hard to open doors. So she squeezed in, and started the engine to move forward, so that the others can open doors and get in easily. Some of my friends didn't understand this and rushed forward, so I said "**Wait, she will drive out**". One of my friends was very surprised to hear that and said, that he has never heard "drive out" being used in such a case before.

Was this a correct usage of the verb? If not, what would be the right words to use in such a case?

Comment: The expression you previously used, _move forward_, might have been clearer.

Comment: I don't find 'drive out' strange or unusual for that situation.